# How to limit file upload in angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, jsajaxfileuploader

I have used [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) to upload files, files are uploading everything working fine.

> Now, I have to add restriction that **user can not able to upload more
>   then 5 pictures and at one shot single file should upload** How is it possible,

Below is my code

**Controller**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Modulename')
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
        var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: site_url+'upload.php'
        });

        // FILTERS

        uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'imageFilter',
            fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
                return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
            }
        });

        // CALLBACKS

        uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
            console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
        };
        uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
            console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
            // fileItem.upload();
        };
        uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
            console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
        };
        uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
            console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
        };
        uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
            console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
        };
        uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
            console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
        };
        uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
            console.info('onCompleteAll');
        };

        console.info('uploader', uploader);
    }]);
```

**View section**

```
<section ng-switch-when="1" class="form-section {{animationClass}} wow" ng-class="{{animationClass}}" ng-controller ="AppController" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader">
        <div class="form-section-block">
            <h3 class="heading text-center">Upload photos</h3>

            <!-- Upload demo area  -->
            <style>
            .my-drop-zone { border: dotted 3px lightgray; }
            .nv-file-over { border: dotted 3px red; } /* Default class applied to drop zones on over */
            .another-file-over-class { border: dotted 3px green; }

            html, body { height: 100%; }

            canvas {
                background-color: #f3f3f3;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #e3e3e3;
                -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #e3e3e3;
                box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 #e3e3e3;
                border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
                height: 100px;
                margin: 6px 0 0 6px;
            }
        </style>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <h3>Select files</h3>

                    <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                        <!-- 3. nv-file-over uploader="link" over-class="className" -->
                        <div class="well my-drop-zone" nv-file-over="" uploader="uploader" options="{autoUpload :'true'}">
                            Base drop zone
                            <input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple  />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-bottom: 40px">


                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="50%">Name</th>
                                <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Size</th>
                                <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Progress</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
                                <td>
                                    <strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong>
                                    <!-- Image preview -->
                                    <!--auto height-->
                                    <!--<div ng-thumb="{ file: item.file, width: 100 }"></div>-->
                                    <!--auto width-->
                                    <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" ng-thumb="{ file: item._file, height: 100 }"></div>
                                    <!--fixed width and height -->
                                    <!--<div ng-thumb="{ file: item.file, width: 100, height: 100 }"></div>-->
                                </td>
                                <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>
                                <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                                    <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                                    <span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                                    <span ng-show="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                                </td>
                                <td nowrap>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="item.cancel()" ng-disabled="!item.isUploading">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="item.remove()">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            Queue progress:
                            <div class="progress" style="">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" ng-click="uploader.uploadAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload all
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s" ng-click="uploader.cancelAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.isUploading">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel all
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s" ng-click="uploader.clearQueue()" ng-disabled="!uploader.queue.length">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove all
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Upload demo area  -->




            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 label-block"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 signup-full-column">
            <div class="stepToggle-btn">
                <span class="">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success up" data-toggle="tooltip" tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="Previous Step" ng-click="previousStep()"><i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success down" data-toggle="tooltip" tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="Next Step" ><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
   </section>
```

Comment: do you mean stop them uploading more than 5 files at a time, or stop them after 5 uploads?

Comment: at one shot upload one single file and not able to upload more then 5 files

Answer (score 0):

You can use the queue limit filter for this

var uploader = new FileUploader({
    queueLimit: 1
});

```
<element nv-file-drop filters="queueLimit"></element>
```

Comment: We can keep that but first we have to restrict to upload single file at single shot